# soap parsing unexpected in complextype

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I can parse the .WSDL file and call the functions using soapUI, but not
using PHP5. It has also been shown to work with JAVA/AXIS and .NET.

I need the WSDL caching functionality of the PHP5 SOAP procedures
otherwise I might stick with soapUI.

### Reproduce code:

```
    $optional = array
    (
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1'
    );

    $wsdl = 'https://www-a.audanet.de/b2b/services/AXAttachmentService?wsdl';
    $client = new SoapClientAuth($wsdl, $optional);
```

### Expected result:

A useable instance of a SoapClient object.

### Actual result:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected 'attribute' in complexType in ../class/SoapClientAuth.php:62
Stack trace:

0 ../class/SoapClientAuth.php(62): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://www-a.a...', Array)

1 ../class/Ws.php(30): SoapClientAuth->SoapClientAuth('https://www-a.a...', Array)

2 ../zalacz.php(468): Ws->podlaczenieWS()

3 {main}

thrown in ../class/SoapClientAuth.php on line 62